# Cannot locate child element Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to pick out single restaurant elements under the **All Restaurants** category on this page. https://www.foodpanda.sg/restaurants/new?lat=1.2915902&lng=103.8379066&vertical=restaurants

[image: Element]

All `li` elements have a different class name. The only working `xpath`, I have been able to figure out is this one.

> //ul[@class="vendor-list"]//li[3]

I cannot figure out how to increase this number and get all the restaurants, which is complicated by the fact that there is an infinite scroll as well.

```
j = 1
def get_rest():
    global j
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,2525)", "")
        time.sleep(5)
        var = f'{[j]}'
        elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f'//ul[@class="vendor-list"]//li{var})
        return elems
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? just get the list of all the restaurants or get some specific restaurant element?

Comment: @Prophet Yes, just all the elements with scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be something like this

```
all_restaurants = set()
restaurant_locator = '//ul[@class="vendor-list"]//li[@data-testid and not(@class)]'
page_bottom_locator = '.restaurants__city-bottom-info'
while #bottom is not reached:
    restaurants = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(restaurant_locator)
    all_restaurants.add(restaurants)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Comment: `'//ul[@class="vendor-list"]//li'` .This `xpath` might not be correct. Can you check. There are multiple `li` elements inside the `li`. It will select child elements with this. Please confirm.

Comment: You are right, updated the locator. Also found the bottom element locator, still not finished :)

Comment: `and not(@class)]'` Damn!! This is champion stuff!! . This works?

Comment: sure, that means there is not class defined in that element.

Comment: Ok, let me try this out.

Comment: `all_restaurants.add(restaurants)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list`  Gives this error. :(

Comment: I had to delete the `set` part. It works. Just the locator was the problem.

Comment: I think you should use set there to avoid duplicates.

Comment: So, How do we fix the `set` error?.You are right duplicates will be an issue. I am having to return these elements ..but. To scrape the info. So, please see that. As of now, I moved the scroll to the first line of the function and am just returning the elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233548/discussion-between-abhishek-rai-and-prophet).

Comment: I pasted the error..right then, Please check the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the `innerHTML` of the `//ul[@class="vendor-list"]//li`

**Code :**

```
driver.get("https://www.foodpanda.sg/restaurants/new?lat=1.2915902&lng=103.8379066&vertical=restaurants")
while True:
    for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='vendor-list']/li"):
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).perform()
      sleep(0.1)
      print(item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: `"//ul[@class='vendor-list']/li"` This `xpath` is not correct, unfortunately. :(

Comment: Run the code, it's working on my system. even I am not doing any indexing I'm taking everything in a list and then performing the iteration

Comment: There's no need to use JS embedded code, when native  `move_to_element` works just fine

Comment: Ah!. Thanks for that. Will try and see.